# Single page template not trigered on Hugo static generator web site

Tags: html, web, hugo, static-generator

I have a problem to trigger a custom single page on my posts.
The content is organised like this :

[image]
With all my posts into the posts folders (I'm no using an _index.md because this folder is one step behind the /content and is considered as a Section for Hugo)

And my layouts look like this (i'm not using a theme) :

[image]

However when i click of one of my post leading to /posts/name-of-post/ URL it renders the layout/default/single.html template. I'm really questioning myself since i saw the [Hugo's Lookup Order](https://gohugo.io/templates/lookup-order/) saying that layout/default/single.html has a lower priority than the layout/section/single.html. Moreover when i delete the default/single.html i got an error saying that no "type" "Page" is implemented. Consequently i'm assuming i'm mistaken on the architecture. Then i saw [this page](https://gohugo.io/templates/single-page-templates/) of the official documentation using the exact same architecture than mine. I need your help to figure out what's wrong in my folder and i can give further details if needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can make a zip available somewhere with your architecture, that would help to review what is going on.